# sql - using group by and count

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables emp and dept:

```
select count(*), dept_id a from xe.dept a group by a.dept_id;

select b.id,b.name from xe.emp b;

a.dept_id = b.id
```

I need the output as:

```
Count, ID, Name
```

Comment: Post you table structure, error and a proper query which was used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
SELECT a.numRows, b.id, b.NAME
FROM xe.emp b
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS numRows, dept_id
  FROM xe.dept
  GROUP BY dept_id
  ) a ON b.id = a.dept_id
```

This gets the COUNT in the inner query for each dept_id and joins it with b to get the id and name.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*), xe.dept.dept_id, xe.emp.Name 
from xe.dept inner join xe.emp on xe.dept.dept_id = xe.emp.id
group by xe.emp.id, xe.emp.Name
```

xe.dept.dept_id = xe.emp.id This link is strange because I would assume that emp.id is the employee id but you said that it matches.